# bootstrap navbar pull-right causing improper formatting

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

![Before and after][1]

[image][2]

```
                    </ul>
          <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><a href="#">Notifications &nbsp;<span class="badge">3</span></a></li>
              </ul>
```

Sorry won't let me post this image yet. The when adding the unordered list the link changes color, is no longer center aligned and what breaks most is the rollover isn't the right height.

Here's the JS Fiddle [JS Fiddle][3]

Comment: There's no link to JSFiddle...

Comment: It seems you have insufficient rep to add the items you need to and thus it's hard to help you unless you include more of your code. I've tried editing, but I can't see any images or fiddles to include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is to add the navbar-nav class